# How to reference variables within an input function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, formatting

I know this is incorrect because 'input()' can only take 1 argument, but I want to include these variables in the input while asking the user to enter more numbers:

```
n = 5
average = 0
for i in range(n):
    numbers = eval(input('Please enter number ', (i+1) ,' of ', n ,' to average:',sep='',end=''))
    average = average+numbers/n
```

Comment: `input` isn't like `print`, it takes a single string to show as the prompt. You have to create that string yourself - Python has several options for string formatting you could do some research on. Also you should almost never use `eval`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string formatting and F-Strings ( only Python 3.6+ )

**String Formatting**:

```
n = 5
average = 0
for i in range(n):
    numbers = int(input('Please enter number {} of {} to average:'.format(i+1, n)))
    average = average+numbers/n
```

**F-Strings** (Works in Python 3.6+):

```
n = 5
average = 0
for i in range(n):
    numbers = int(input(f'Please enter number {i+1} of {n} to average:'))
    average = average+numbers/n
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try concatenating your variables after converting them to string [str(x)]

```
n = 5
average = 0
for i in range(n):
    numbers = eval(input('Please enter number '+str(i+1)+' of '+str(n)+' to average:'))
    average = average+numbers/n
```

This is a naive approach but works fine.